# What will be test URL for Skrill test checkout?

Tags: api, payment-gateway, skrill

What will be tested URL for Skrill test checkout?

Right now I am using this https://pay.skrill.com
And I believe that somewhere it is not accepting test transaction it only accepting production (live) transactions.

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Automated_Payments_Interface_Guide.pdf):

> Skrill recommends that you open a merchant test account to help you become familiar with the
>   Automated Payments Interface. Test accounts operate in the live environment, but funds cannot be
>   sent from a test account to a live account.
>
> To obtain a test account, please register a personal account at http://www.skrill.com, and then contact the
>   [Merchant Services team](http://merchantservices@skrill.com) with the account details so that they can enable it.